# did visual c++ 6.0 support unicode?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6

i must migrate a c++ 6.0 project to visual c++ 2010 project.First, i must convert prj to unicode ,then convert to vs 2010.I confuse that did visual c++ 6.0  support unicode ?how to know it
thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it supported Unicode exactly as the most recent version does. Setting the Unicode flag in your project produces a `#define` of the `_UNICODE` constant, which changes the names of the Windows API functions and changes CString to use wchar_t instead of char.

Comment: In VC++6 you also have to set the entry-point symbol to `wWinMainCRTStartup`.

Comment: @john_e, most of my experience comes from setting up a new project, not changing an existing one. The New Project Wizard makes that change for you automatically.

Comment: @Mark: _UNICODE is for the CRT and UNICODE is for WinAPI (Usually you set both)

Comment: @john_e: That is the entry point for applications not using the CRT, he probably just wants the normal wWinMain