# Check whether a Visual C++ 6.0 project did support unicode or not?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I need to know if a Visual C++ 6.0 project supports Unicode or not. How can I check that?

Comment: Why don't people proof-read their questions...

Comment: Because they don't care.

Comment: possible duplicate of [did visual c++ 6.0 support unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10492690)

Answer (score 4):

If the project is compiled with Unicode support, then the preprocessor directive `UNICODE` (or `_UNICODE`) will be defined. Testing to see if this is defined will give you your answer:

```
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
    // The project is compiled for Unicode
#else
    // The project is NOT compiled for Unicode
#endif
```

You can also check this from within your project's settings.

1. From the "Project" menu, click "Settings".
2. Select the "C/C++" tab.
3. In the "Preprocessor definitions" section, check for the presence of `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`.

If you have a project that is *not* currently targeting Unicode, but you want to see if it *can*, then the best thing to do would be to define these preprocessor directives, and then try compiling your project. If it succeeds, then you're set. If it fails, go through and correct the errors emitted by the compiler.

Comment: after i check i see my project is not targeting unicode , it is targeting multibyte character set.Now how to know my source code can targeting unicode.I see all parameter in methods is char type instead of wchar_t, may i concluded it is not targeting unicode?

Comment: @nguyen: If it's targeting the multibyte character set (MBCS), then it is *not* targeting Unicode. And if you've used the `char` type, instead of the `TCHAR` type like you're supposed to, then you will not be able to recompile it for Unicode by simply adding `#define UNICODE`. You'll need to rewrite the code, either to use `TCHAR` with Unicode defined, or `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#   error Success!
#endif
```