# How to loop through files in a folder in VC++6.0

Tags: c++, winapi

**Background:**

I am currently working on a legacy application on VC++6.
I am trying to create a function to loop through all the files in a directory and get all its file paths.

On my own machine, I used Visual Studio2017 and the following code works. However, when I  implement it on VC++6, it fails.

> And when I try to compile, mainly 2 types of errors are shown

```
error C2664: 'FindFirstFileA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const unsigned short *' to 'const char *'

error C2782: 'class std::basic_string<_E,_Tr,_A> __cdecl std::operator +(const class std::basic_string<_E,_Tr,_A> &,const _E)' : template parameter '_E' is ambiguous
        could be 'char *'
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

> C++ Code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 bool ListFiles(wstring path, wstring mask,    vector<wstring>& files) {
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
wstring spec;
stack<wstring> directories;

directories.push(path);
files.clear();

while (!directories.empty()) {
    path = directories.top();
    spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
    directories.pop();

    hFind = FindFirstFile(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  {
        return false;
    } 

    do {
        if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 && 
            wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
            if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
            }
            else {
                files.push_back(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
        FindClose(hFind);
        return false;
    }

    FindClose(hFind);
    hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
vector<wstring> files;

if (ListFiles(L"D:\\test", L"*", files)) {
    for (vector<wstring>::iterator it = files.begin   (); 
         it != files.end(); 
         ++it) {
        wcout << it->c_str() << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your program is compiling for ANSI characters rather than wide characters. When you see function you called showing up in error messages with an `A` suffix, your compiler has been instructed to compile the old 8-bit characters. Danged if I can remember where in Visual Studio 6 you'll find the option to force wide characters.

Comment: Here is a better exp[lanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/generic-text-mappings-in-tchar-h?view=vs-2019

Comment: You could call `FindFirstFileW` explicitly.  I would recommend you set your project up to define `_UNICODE` though.

Comment: There will be a be an option on a property page somewhere in the project options you can set. Otherwise you `#define _UNICODE`... Ah HA! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494859/check-whether-a-visual-c-6-0-project-did-support-unicode-or-not Cody Grey's answer tells you where the option is hidden.

Comment: @user4581301, Miles Budnek, have tried both of yr suggestion, the error still remains. Is there a better way to do it in VC++6

Comment: Interesting The Cody link should have fixed it all up. Have you tried forcing `FindFirstFileW`? You'll also need to force `FindNextFileW`, etc...

Comment: @user4581301, have tried , but sadly more error error C2664: 'FindNextFileW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAA *' to 'struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAW *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: Use `string` instead of `wstring` and remove all the `L`'s from your strings. To say the STL in Visual Studio 6 was a bit quirky is being very kind. Good luck!. Yuo can also use the actual type `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`. Basically if it complains about SomethingA, change it to SomethingW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default your project is configured to use narrow (ANSI) system functions. `FindFirstFile` is translated to `FindFirstFileA` and `WIN32_FIND_DATA` to `WIN32_FIND_DATAA`.

You can reconfigure your project by defining `UNICODE`, `_UNICODE` and removing `_MBCS`.

Menu `Project`->`Settings...`.

Before:

[image: _MBCS defined]

After:

[image: UNICODE and _UNICODE defined]

Comment: `_UNICODE` has no effect in context of this question. It's the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol that controls the generic-text mappings in the Windows API. Arguably, a far superior solution would be to not rely on any mappings at all, and simply call `FindFirstFileW` (and friends). The resulting code is unaffected by the environment (IDE or project settings), and won't change its meaning when copy-pasted across environments.

Comment: `_UNICODE` is for t-macros and was added just in case. This is how newer Visual Studio versions configure new project when "Use Unicode Character Set" is selected. Even if you prefer to use `FindFirstFileW` you should define `UNICODE` to avert unintended use of A-functions.

Comment: @DanielSęk `_UNICODE`, `_TCHAR`, and `_T()` apply to the C runtime library. `UNICODE`, `TCHAR`, and `TEXT()` apply to the Win32 API. Setting "Use Unicode Character Set" enables both `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE`