# How to read unicode source file in VC6.0 source window?

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-c++-6

I am restricted on a VC6.0 project, under Windows 7 (Chinese), and I want to read some cpp files that contains unicode characters. For example:

```
char const * const locales[] = {
"العربية",
"Български",
"繁體中文",
"简体中文",
"hrvatski",
"čeština",
"English",
"français",
"Deutsch",
"Ελληνικά",
"עברית",
"हिंदी",
"日本語",
"Қазақ",
"한국어‫",
"latviešu",
"lietuvių",
"bokmål",
"Português",
"română",
"Русский",
"slovenčina",
"Español",
"ไทย",
"Türkçe",
"українська",
"Tiếng Việt"
};
```

If the cpp file is saved as ASNI by notepad++, it will lose some contents like the graph:
[image: ASNI picture]

If it is saved as Unicode by notepad++, it will become corrupted like:

[image: unicode picture]

How can I correctly show those characters in the IDE?

Comment: You can, but why? As soon as you save the cpp file in a UTF encoding, you will find out that `char *` is not an acceptable storage for them anyway.

Comment: Maybe my example is wrong, I get to use WCHAR * or something similar.

Comment: From what I remember of Visual Studio 6, it didn't support unicode characters in source.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It would appear you're right. While the [compiler understands Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10492690/11683), the IDE does not.

Comment: So you will have to take a hex representation and initialize string using binary representaion